# Asymptotic lines of a parametrized surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, parametrization

> Prove that the lines $v=k\pi$ are asymptotic lines for the surface parametrized by $$\varphi:(0,\pi )\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{3}$$
> $$\varphi (u,v)=(v,\cos(u),\sin(v))$$

Honestly, I don't know how to proceed because the professor talk with us only about the $v$ or $u-lines$ like $\varphi (u_{0}+t,v)$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$

Can someone axplain this concept? Thanks before!

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo? Every $u$-curve is a line segment, hence an asymptotic curve. The surface is a cylinder whose base is a sine curve. When $v=k\pi$ (for $k$ an integer), you have an inflection point of the sine curve and therefore planar points of the surface.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, we can plot the function using *Mathematica*:[image]

I do **not** think it have any "asymptotic lines".

Comment: Do you know what asymptotic curves (lines) are? Any line contained in a surface is automatically one.

Comment: I know what you mean. But as you see, $u\in(0,\pi)$ and does not extent to $\mathbb R$, so I doubt that to be the answer.

Comment: The word “line” is being used for “curve,” not a literal line.

Comment: Fine. Then it's true that $u$-curve is an asymptotic line.